# What is the ideal AWS region for use with Rackspace servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

We have servers in Rackspace's Dallas region that occasionally need to interact with AWS (`EC2`, `S3`, `SNS`, etc.)

Of the three major regions in the US ...

- US East (Northern Virginia)
- US West (Northern California)
- US West (Oregon)

Which one would be ideal to choose for working with Rackspace?

By "ideal" I mostly mean in terms of things like network latency, etc. I could guess vaguely using purely physical distance but as that wouldn't take into account a lot of other important variables, I'm interested in some real world examples or experiences.

Answer (score 3):

As an anecdote, in a previous job, we had a small two-vendor deployment with RAX/AWS. Our reason was HA/DR, not network optimization, so we chose AWS West 2 region and ORD for RAX. That said, we didn't notice the network latency was an issue even when dealing with the long geographical distance between said data centers. Also to bear in mind is that geographical proximity might not have a correlation with low network latency in these cases. It really depends on the backbone providers each vendor has and the number of hops in between.

Now if you intend to run, say, a MongoDB cluster in a region of AWS and a replica set in RAX or any other such more complicated scenarios, I would strongly suggest you run a few small deployment tests and see what works best for you guys. Better to invest a few dollars testing than to commit to a solution that might look good on paper but doesn't work in practice. That's the beauty of utility-priced, throw-away computing :)